# TASCAM US-122 en 2024

Tags: sound, alsa

Hola soy un fanático de Linux y me gusta usarlo para la producción musical. Trabaje con la conocida interfaz Behringer UM22, en AV linux el cual me lo reconoció al instante y funcionaba bien, sin embargo la tuve que devolver porque era de mi amigo.

Ahora por un intercambio obtuve esta TASCAM US-122 pense que seria lo mismo (que el sistema lo reconozca al instante) sin embargo no funcionó. Investigué por los foros, enterándome que era algo relacionado con viejas versiones de ubuntu (6.06... etc.) intente de varias formas con la conocida "usx2y" y el "alsa-firmware", logré encender la interfaz pero no lograba usarlo porque no lo reconocía del todo y/o muchos errores.

Repito que los "controladores" de alsa para esta interfaz provienen de años atrás mas o menos desde el 2006.

estoy por instalar ubuntu studio 22.04 para intentar que funcione la interfaz

Espero sus respuestas, Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Please translate your question into English before posting it.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This platform is a English only site. Kindly [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506474/edit) your question and translate you question into English language.